# What does HTTP status code 602 mean

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-webhooks

Facebook webhook is returning HTTP 602 :
[image]

What does 602 mean/stand for?

Answer (score 1):

There is no **standard** HTTP status code starting with 6 (Standard HTTP status codes start with 1 - 5).

Vendors like facebook / google assign their own meaning to HTTP status code starting with 6.

Answer (score 0):

It is a custom code used by facebook. There is not an official listing for the current http code. In the list below there seems to be an connection with current known http codes and their meanings in it so I would speculate that it means:

```
The description is The field you requested does not exist.
```

Check it here:
[error codes](http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html)

Comment: That document is about API error codes, not HTTP status codes. Plus, 602 is listed as an FQL-related error code - FQL has been gone for ages now.